# Simple Pointer Question

Tags: c++, pointers

**edit**: nevermind, solved...I'd declared type in *ClassB* AND *ClassC*....

So I have a pointer, named *PointA*, in a class called *ClassA*.

*ClassA* and *ClassB* are both derived from *ClassC*, which has a variable called *type*.

In a section of code I assign a new instance of *ClassB* to *ClassA*'s *PointA* variable. The pointer is declared to point to *ClassC*, of which *ClassB* is derived from.

I then have a function, in *OtherClass* (irrelevant), that looks a bit like this:

```
void OtherClass::function_name(ClassA* A,ClassB* B) {
    B->type; //displays the correct value of type

    A->PointA->type; //displays the wrong value of type
    (A->PointA)->type; //displays the wrong value of type
}
```

I know that *PointA* points correctly to the instance of *ClassB*.

What am I doing wrong to get the incorrect value of *type* when I use the pointer?

Comment: How are ClassA and ClassB related? You should post all the code, including class definitions.

Comment: Did you try `A->PointA->type`?

Comment: You didn't post nearly enough code.  Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: I've also added some more code...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did an illegal cast when populating PointA.  ClassB needs to be a subclass of the thing that PointA is defined to point to ( typeof(*ClassA->PointA) ) or else what you are trying to do will not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, both `ClassA` and `ClassB` have a member named `type`. Since you can make your `PointA` point to either `ClassA` object or `ClassB` object, there must be a parent-child relationship between these classes (is there?). If so, are you sure that you did not create two completely unrelated `type` members: one in `ClassA` and another in `ClassB`? You expect to inspect `ClassB::type`, but in fact you inspect `ClassA::type`, which is why you see a different ("wrong") value.

You need to post more code, to show us how the classes are declared. With what you posted one can only make wild guesses... On top of that, the code you posted is obviously "fake", i.e. it is not the code you made your experiments with. The `ClassA->PointA->type` expression will not even compile. Post real code.

Comment: Sorry, there is yes. ClassC...I forgot to add that detail. Fixed post.